# Connect Azure Logic App to On Premise FTP Server using Azure Hybrid Connection

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-logic-apps

I am currently exploring a way to connect Azure Logic App to be able to fetch file from on-premise FTP server. What I have found in Azure documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp#connect-to-ftp, that it is possible to do so.

> If you have an on-premises FTP server, consider creating an
> integration service environment (ISE) or using Azure App Service
> Hybrid connections, which both let you access on-premises data sources
> without using an on-premises data gateway.

So I am interested to use Azure App Service Hybrid connections for this, but what I don't know is how to connect ftp connector in logic apps to Hybrid connections set in Azure App service. The documentation for Azure Hybrid connection didn't mention about how to do this.

If anyone knows how to connect Azure Logic App to on-premise FTP server via Azure App Service Hybrid connections, appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Comment: You can directly connect to FTP using Logic App without Hybrid Connection, is there a specific use-case which is why you need to try hybrid connection

Comment: @PratikSomaiya I think if the FTP is not accessible from internet, then we need some sort of mechanism as a bridge between the on-premise FTP and Azure. The logic apps mentions that the Azure Hybrid connection is the possible solution. But I still don't know on how to use logic apps with Azure hybrid connection

Comment: ok, please check if below answer suffice the requirement

Answer (score 0):

To create a Hybrid connection to FTP, try the following steps:

1. In Azure App Service, open Networking tab in the left pane
2. Go to Configure your Hybrid Connection endpoints
3. Click on Add hybrid connection
4. Click on Create new hybrid connection and add following information:

   a) Hybrid Connection name

   b) Endpoint hostname

   c) Endpoint port

   d) Service Bus namespace you want to use (Every Hybrid Connection is tied to a Service Bus namespace, and each Service Bus namespace is in an Azure region)

Then you can connect the App Service with the Logic App

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I still don't understand how to connect Logic App with App Service. What I read from Azure App Service connector for Logic Apps documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureappservice/), the connector is only for starting, restarting and stopping web app. I'm not sure on how to use this for getting files from FTP server

Comment: You can call the FTP API from your Logic App workflow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-custom-api-host-deploy-call#call-your-custom-api-from-logic-app-workflows